# Gem install confusing the ruby version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant

I'm attempting to install `vagrant-bindfs` through the `vagrant up`, however it was failing, and the same happened with `vagrant plugin install vagrant-bindfs`.

So I've downloaded the gem file and attempted to install it manually, as you can see below:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
~/.vagrant.d/gems/gems » gem install -l ~/Downloads/vagrant-bindfs-0.4.12.gem --install-dir . --debug
NOTE:  Debugging mode prints all exceptions even when rescued
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.2/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:171 - LoadError
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.2/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/ml/.vagrant.d/gems/gems
Exception `Gem::InstallError' at /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:611 - vagrant-bindfs requires Ruby version ~> 2.0.0.
ERROR:  Error installing /Users/ml/Downloads/vagrant-bindfs-0.4.12.gem:
    vagrant-bindfs requires Ruby version ~> 2.0.0.
------------------------------------------------------------
~/.vagrant.d/gems/gems » gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.2 (2016-11-15 patchlevel 217) [x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/ml/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/ml/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
     - /Users/ml/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - .
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/ml/.composer/vendor/bin
```

So as it mentions above it requires `~> 2.0.0`, and the version gem is using is `RUBY VERSION: 2.3.2`, which should be ok.

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: By your Ruby environment I may say you are using your native Ruby, the one that came as a package with your Linux distribution. I suggest you not to do this. Install RVM or RBENV and install Ruby using one of them. This will make your Ruby installation to be done in user space and you will not suffer from permission problems. It is probably something related to this which is happening.

Comment: Initially I was using osx system ruby, but installed a version through `brew` and I'm currently using that one, which is the one mentioned above (version `2.3.2`)

Comment: And the error, is not due to permissions, but to wrong version, as it can handle the exceptions, but fails on error, or am I wrong?

Comment: This is not going to install the gem into a place where Vagrant can find it. You need to go a different route here.

Comment: Yes but the issue is not where it installs it, is that is not even able to install it